# Programmatically create Artemis cluster on remote server

Tags: activemq-artemis

Is it possible to programmatically create/update a cluster on a remote Artemis server?
I will have lots of docker instances and would rather configure on the fly than have to set in XML files if possible.

Ideally on app launch I'd like to check if a cluster has been set up and if not create one.
This would probably involve getting the current server configuration and updating it with the cluster details.

I see it's possible to create a Configuration.
However, I'm not sure how to get the remote server configuration, if it's at all possible.

```
            Configuration config = new ConfigurationImpl();
            ClusterConnectionConfiguration ccc = new ClusterConnectionConfiguration();
            ccc.setAddress("231.7.7.7");
            config.addClusterConfiguration(ccc);
            
            // need a way to get and update the current server configuration
            ActiveMQServer.getConfiguration();
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

If it is possible, is this a good approach to take to configure on the fly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.config.impl.ConfigurationImpl` object can be used to programmatically configure the broker. The broker test-suite uses this object to configure broker instances. However, this object is not available in any remote sense.

Once the broker is started there is a rich management API you can use to add things like security settings, address settings, diverts, bridges, addresses, queues, etc. However, the changes made by most (although not all) of these operations are volatile which means many of them would need to be performed every time the broker started. Furthermore, there are no management methods to add cluster connections.

You might consider using a tool like [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) to manage the configuration or even roll your own solution with a templating engine like [FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/) to customize the XML and then distribute it to your Docker instances using some other technology.

Comment: Thanks good to know. I suspected it was not possible. I'll mount the /etc directory in Docker and will look at using XInclude to split up the broker.xml.